# can't call some methods in framework from swift

Tags: ios, swift, methods, frameworks

I have the following two methods in an custom objective c framework

```
- (void) callWithProfile:(UserProfile *) user number:(NSString *) number name:(NSString *)name instructions:(NSString *)instructions
{
    //
}

// Make call connection
- (void) startConnecting
{
   //
}
```

and I can call startConnecting with

```
 let socket : SocketSingleton = SocketSingleton()
       socket.startConnecting()
```

but it won't let me call callWithProfile. Both methods are declared in the header file and there are no errors in the framework. How can I call the other method from my swift project?

Comment: Have you added bridging header ?

Comment: yes I it has been added

Comment: Did you declare the method in your header file?

Comment: Can you please try with var instead of let once ?
I think this will be stupid suggestion but working for me in one case.

Comment: Yes it is declared in my header.

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift

Comment: I tried with var and no go. At first I thought it had something to do with the methods but out of these 3 methods, I can access handleDisconnect but not the first and last so it has nothing to do with the method structure - (void) callWithProfile:(UserProfile *) user number:(NSString *) number name:(NSString *)name instructions:(NSString *)instructions;
- (void) handleDisconnect:(bool)stayConnected netDown:(int)netDown;
- (void) declineInboundCallWithProfile:(UserProfile *) profile andNumber:(NSString *) number andName:(NSString *)name;

Comment: Pushkraj I have read through that but it doesn't give the answer. My bridging header connecting is working since I can call some methods from my framework and they are in the same controller.